# Blazor hybrid cant add migration

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, blazor, migration, hybrid

Hey i have a blazor hybrid app using sqlite and ef. I am planning to deploy it to android.
When i try to add migration i am getting :

The specified deps.json [C:\Users\sipah\Desktop\serdar\projeler\PersonalProjects\DersTakipV2\bin\Debug\net8.0-android\DersTakipV2.deps.json] does not exist

1- There is only one project and it is startup project.
2- I have dbcontext :

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string databasePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "Ders.db");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DersContext>(options => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={databasePath}"));
```

3- I have the model.

In a classic Blazor or MVC this should has no problem.
Any help appreciated.

I have added microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite
code builds but cannot add migration